# How do I query values ​from XML nodes using the XML query function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xpath, sqlxml

I have the following XML data:

```
DECLARE @x XML   
SET @x='<Orders>
<HeadingSection>
    <DocumentNameCode>Order</DocumentNameCode>
    <DetailSection>
        <LineItem LineItemNumber="10">
            <ItemId>123456789</ItemId>
            <ItemTypeId>EN</ItemTypeId>
            <AdditionalProductId Qualifier="ProductId">
                <Item>
                <ItemId>ABC</ItemId>
                <TypeId>SA</TypeId>
                </Item>
            </AdditionalProductId>
            <AdditionalProductId Qualifier="ProductId">
                <Item>
                <ItemId>XYZ</ItemId>
                <TypeId>IN</TypeId>
                </Item>
            </AdditionalProductId>
        </LineItem>
    </DetailSection>
    <SummarySection/>
</HeadingSection>
</Orders>'
```

I already use the following T-SQL script (must have a cursor)

```
DECLARE @xmlQuittungPOS XML
DECLARE quittungCurPOS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT QuittungXMLPOS = T.X.query('.')         
    FROM @x.nodes('/Orders/HeadingSection/DetailSection/LineItem') AS T(X)  
    
OPEN quittungCurPOS
    
FETCH NEXT FROM quittungCurPOS INTO @xmlQuittungPOS
    
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.tempPOS (

GTIN
,edi_PIA_SA
,edi_PIA_IN

)


SELECT

GTIN = T.X.query('/LineItem[ItemTypeId = "BP"]').value('(/LineItem/ItemId)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') -- funktioniert / works

,edi_PIA_SA = T.X.query('/LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item[TypeId = "SA"]').value('(/LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item/ItemId)[1]','VARCHAR(255)') -- funktioniert nicht / doesn't work

,edi_PIA_IN = T.X.query('/LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item[TypeId = "IN"]').value('(/LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item/ItemId)[1]','VARCHAR(255)') -- funktioniert nicht / doesn't work

FROM 
@xmlQuittungPOS.nodes('/LineItem') AS T(X)
    
FETCH NEXT FROM quittungCurPOS INTO @xmlQuittungPOS
END

CLOSE quittungCurPOS
DEALLOCATE quittungCurPOS
```

1. GTIN -> query works
2. PIA_SA and PIA_IN -> query doesn't work

Question:

I think it's because `/LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item[TypeId = "SA"]` are in additional nodes.

Question:

How do I get the values of TypeId "SA" and "IN" ​​in

```
<AdditionalProductId Qualifier="ProductId">
<Item>
<ItemId>**ABC**</ItemId>
<TypeId>SA</TypeId>
</Item>
</AdditionalProductId>

<AdditionalProductId Qualifier="ProductId">
<Item>
<ItemId>**XYZ**</ItemId>
<TypeId>IN</TypeId>
</Item>
</AdditionalProductId>
```

with .value('(/LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item/ItemId)[1]','VARCHAR(255)')

! at Level 1 !

I know.

SA on Level 1 -> .value('(/LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item/ItemId)[**1**]','VARCHAR(255)')
SA on Level 2 -> .value('(/LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item/ItemId)[**2**]','VARCHAR(255)')

but I now need the query for the type

Thanks

Comment: Your post is a little malformed. What is the end result you are expecting here? 1 row with 2 columns, or 1 column with 2 rows?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You don't need to repeat the full path in `value()` after `query()` and in doing so gives an incorrect path, hence no value. You can simply use `T.X.query('LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item[TypeId = "IN"]').value('(Item/ItemId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')`. But you can filter in the `value()` method too, so you can just use `T.X.value('(LineItem/AdditionalProductId/Item[TypeId = "SA"]/ItemId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')`. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rhizWlnQ)

Comment: As an aside, I fail to see why your query **must have a cursor**. You can insert multiple line items with a [single statement pretty easily](https://dbfiddle.uk/UMpdRKBb)

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you are after here, so I'm answering for both. If you want 1 row per `Item` node, then you just need to use `nodes` to the `Item` node and get the `value` of `ItemId` text:

```sql
DECLARE @xml xml = '<AdditionalProductId Qualifier="ProductId">
<Item>
<ItemId>**ABC**</ItemId>
<TypeId>SA</TypeId>
</Item>
</AdditionalProductId>

<AdditionalProductId Qualifier="ProductId">
<Item>
<ItemId>**XYZ**</ItemId>
<TypeId>IN</TypeId>
</Item>
</AdditionalProductId>
';

SELECT AP.I.value('(ItemId/text())[1]','varchar(15)') AS ItemId,
       AP.I.value('(TypeId/text())[1]','varchar(15)') AS TypeId
FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X) --To give impression it's against a table
      CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes ('AdditionalProductId/Item')AP(I);
```

if, however, you want 1 column per different value of `TypeID` you could either  filter in the XML:

```sql
SELECT X.AP.value('(AdditionalProductId/Item[TypeId[(text()[1])="SA"]]/ItemId/text())[1]','varchar(15)') AS ItemSA,
       X.AP.value('(AdditionalProductId/Item[TypeId[(text()[1])="IN"]]/ItemId/text())[1]','varchar(15)') AS ItemIN
FROM @xml.nodes ('/')X(AP); --To give impression it's against a table
```

Or use the prior query and use conditional aggregation:

```sql
WITH Items AS(
    SELECT AP.I.value('(ItemId/text())[1]','varchar(15)') AS ItemId,
           AP.I.value('(TypeId/text())[1]','varchar(15)') AS TypeId
    FROM @xml.nodes ('AdditionalProductId/Item')AP(I))
SELECT MAX(CASE TypeID WHEN 'SA' THEN ItemId END) AS ItemSA,
       MAX(CASE TypeID WHEN 'IN' THEN ItemId END) AS ItemIN
FROM Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and I have found my solution for now.

```
value('(AdditionalProductId/Item[TypeId[(text()[1])="SA"]]/ItemId/text())[1]
```

I would be happy to see the other tips

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**